# How to set tint color for setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds?

Tags: android, image, android-vectordrawable, tint

I have a tab layout in which i am setting the text and vector image like this:

```
    TextView tab2 = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
    tab2.setText("OFFER");
    tab2.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.ic_offer, 0, 0);
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setCustomView(tab2));
```

How can i change the tint color for the drawable vector image?

Answer (score 4):

Try like this:

```
Drawable drawables[] = textView.getCompoundDrawables();
drawables[0].setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
```